# How to get models and order by related model's column Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two related models (many-to-many) - Fabrics and Colors, and tables - fabrics, colors, and fabrics_colors (id, fabric_id, color_id). The Color model has simple columns - just id, name, and code. What I need is very simple: to get (paginate) fabrics with colors and order these fabrics by the color's name. It is worth noting that the fabrics model may not have related colors at all.

I tried this:

```php
return Fabrics::with('colors')->with(['colors' => function($query){
    return $query->orderBy('name','asc');
}])->paginate($pageSize);

// I also tried it without return 
return Fabrics::with('colors')->with(['colors' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('name','asc');
}])->paginate($pageSize);
```

I can retrieve the fabrics, but it seems that the ordering didn't work as it was supposed to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVUoC.png)

I expected to get the fabrics that have colors and be ordered by the color's name first, and then all others. However, I got randomly ordered fabrics with no colors, and only somewhere in the middle are the fabrics with colors. I have tried all query types, such as where, with, and joins, but none of them worked. I have attempted all variants of querying:

P.S I declared all relations in both models - Fabrics and Colors.

```php
return Fabrics::join('colors','colors.id','=','fabrics_colors.color_id')->orderBy('colors.name','acs')->paginate($pageSize);

Fabrics::join('colors','colors.id','=','fabrics_colors.color_id')->orderBy('color.name','acs')->paginate($pageSize);
```

I tried all variants of querying. I would appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: `::with('colors')->with(['colors' => ...])` is incorrect usage; the 2nd will completely override the first, so it's redundant to use both. Use `with('colors')` **OR** `with(['colors' => ...])`, not both. Also, the `return` is optional. That being said, you can't sort `Fabrics` by an `orderBy` clause of `colors`; they are 2 separate queries, `with()` doesn't do any kind of joins, but executes a Subquery. Your last 2 queries are actually the correct approach; do they not work?

Comment: Oh, it's just a typo, it wasn't in my code, just here while I was writing the question ). What about my last two queries, when I used joins, I got this error: 
Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table \"fabrics_colors "\nLINE 1: ... \"fabrics\" inner join \"colors\

Comment: Ah ok; no worries. Chaining `with()` is valid, when you want to load _different_ relationships, like `::with('colors')->with('sizes')` (for example, but would still be better written as `::with(['colors', 'sizes'])`, etc.). For your second query, I think you're missing another Join, as I suspect you have 3 tables; `fabrics`, `colors` and `fabrics_colors`, but you only have 1 `join` clause.